# Applying Gronwall's Inequality

Tags: integration, limsup-and-liminf

I've been working on this problem and was able to get it down to this inequality:

$$E[\log X_t] \leq ae^{-t} + b(1-e^{-t}) + e^{-t}\int_0^t e^sE[\log X_s] ds$$

I'd like to use Gronwall's Inequality to determine an expression for $\limsup E[\log X_t]$

So using Gronwall's Inequality, I get:

$$E[\log X_t] \leq ae^{-t} + b(1-e^{-t}) + \int_0^t \left[ae^{-s} + b(1-e^{-s})\right]e^se^{\int_s^t e^r dr}$$

So the $``ae^{-t} + b(1-e^{-t})"$ -term outside the integral is easy. Inside the integral is where I seem to get stuck.

The integral becomes:

$$\int_0^t \left[a + b(e^s-1)\right]e^{e^t-e^s} ds = e^{e^t}\int_0^t \frac{a-b}{e^{e^s}} + \frac{be^s}{e^{e^s}} ds$$

I have no idea how to compute that. I don't really need an explicit answer but I need to compute the $\limsup_{t \rightarrow \infty}$ of that expression. I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: I didn't check whether you applied the gronwall inequality correctly but when it comes to the integral you state in your last line - why don't you just compute it? substitute $\exp(s)$

Comment: @user190080 I don't see any feasible way to compute it. Using u-substitution, I get $$\int \frac{a-b}{ue^u} + \frac{b}{e^u} du$$. Second term is fine but the first term I don't think has any nice solution

Comment: $\int \frac{e^s}{e^{e^s}}ds=\int \frac{1}{e^u} du$, you made a mistake in your substitution I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just a question about the real valued function $u(t) = E[\log X_t]$. Your inequality says
$$
u(t) \le  ae^{-t} + b(1-e^{-t}) + e^{-t}\int_0^t e^s u(s) ds
$$
or equivalently with $v(t) = e^tu(t)$
$$
v(t) \le  a + b(e^t-1) + \int_0^t v(s) ds
$$
Now Gronwall's Lemma implies that
$$
v(t) \le a + b(e^t - 1) + \int_0^t (a + b(e^s-1))e^{t-s}ds \\
=  e^t(a+b(t-1)) +b-a \, .
$$
Therefore,
$$
E[\log X_t] = u(t) \le e^{-t} v(t) = (a+b(t-1)) + (b-a)e^{-t} \, .
$$
Unfortunately, this does not give a $t$-independent bound for $\limsup_t E[\log X_t]$.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't recognize the trick of seeing $v(t) = e^tu(t)$. I appreciate it. Hopefully I'll find  away to give a t-independent bound.